# It is not possible to switch on frame with chromedriver=2.34

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I launch automatic test on  chrome v.63 with `chromedriver=2.34`.
After test has been switched to iframe next elements are not founded (`NoSuchElement` exceptions appeared).
For example simple code:

```
    wd.switchTo().frame(filemanagerFrame);
    System.out.println(wd.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mediafile-file-fileupload\"]/h3")).getText());
```

And I catched *org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="mediafile-file-fileupload"]/h3"}*

Also I've tried to add `new WebDriverWait(wd, 15).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(filemanagerFrame));` or  `Thread.sleep(1000);` but it also hasn't helped.

Maybe there could be bug with new `chromedriver`? Or I don't know other solutions.

p.s. Element is visible and test is successful with chromedriver2.33. Question is why..

Comment: when I've downgraded chromedriver version to 2.33 it works as expected

Comment: show us the iframe and what you try to do with it, not just the switch to it

Answer (score 1):

I've had to add 2-second sleeps after my frame switches on ChromeDriver 2.34